# how can I split a string into an array

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop

i have a problem why dispense doesn't get the amount of data that has been calculated by the loop.

why the demo2 doesn't count all the data totals and how to calculate the amount of data in the demo2?

```js
const demo1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15];

const demo2 = "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15";
const array_demo2 = [demo2];

let text1 = "";
let number1 = "";
for (let i = 0; i < demo1.length; i++) {
  number1 = (i + 1);
  text1 += demo1[i];
}

let text2 = "";
let number2 = "";
for (let i = 0; i < array_demo2.length; i++) {
  number2 = (i + 1);
  text2 += array_demo2[i];
}

document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = number1 +' = '+ text1;
document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = number2 +' = '+ text2;
```

```html
<div style="display: flex"><p>Output 1 =></p>&nbsp;<p id="demo1"></p></div>
<div style="display: flex"><p>Output 2 =></p>&nbsp;<p id="demo2"></p></div>
```

Comment: Your array_demo2 contains only one element - "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15". Use .split(...) method to split string into array.

Comment: I recommend learning how to debug code. You can use your browser's devtools for example. If you had executed the code line by line and looked at each variable and thought why it contains what it contains, you would have noticed the problem yourself, and then your question would have been "how can I split a string into an array" and not "why is my loop not working". It's a lot easier then to find solutions for such a specific problem here or on Google then.

Comment: @CherryDT, Sorry for the title of my problem, because I don't know what it's called. I have replaced it with your suggestion. I'm new to loop js and I'll try to do better in the future. thank you for the advice you gave.

Comment: @wiihii I didn't mean to just criticize the title of the question, what I meant was that this skill of debugging code and using step-by-step execution helps you to arrive at a different definition of what your actual problem is. And usually this then makes it much easier to find a solution yourself, which means you can move much faster with your development because you don't have to wait for others to understand and help with your issue. In this example, debugging would have showed you that `array_demo2.length` is 1 and that there is that single element in the array, unlike in the other array.

Comment: (Unfortunately most tutorials and also university lectures fail to teach this vital thing in the early stages. In my opinion it should be taught on day 2, right after the first hello world.)

Answer (score 0):

demo1 is an array, meaning multiple variables of the same type inside a container (the array is the container)

demo2 is a single variable, a string. you can

```
demo2.split(','); // to get an array like demo1, but it will be an array of strings.
```

array_demo2 is an array with a single element, the demo2 string. You can

```
array_demo2[0].split(','); // to get an array like demo2/demo1
```

[Read more about arrays here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/introduction-to-arrays/)
The text is for C/++ but in Javascript arrays are very similiar.

Answer (score 0):

```
const demo2 = "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15";
const array_demo2 = [demo2];
```

this is not the correct way to convert it to number you're just passing a string in an array which will be on it's first index, so this array will have only 1 length.

its same like if you do lets say:

```
let fruit = "apple"
let fruits = [fruit];
```

fruits array will always have only one fruit on its first index.
so the correct way is to use the `.split` method of array, so in your case it would be something

```
const demo2 = "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15";
const array_demo2 = demo2.split(",");
```

now it will split each number seprated by "," and add it to new index on the array.